# Dealing with absolute value norm in multiple integral type questions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a common question concerning the three integral questions below.
I don't know how to deal with terms like $|x|$. I can parameterize both the region of integration or the integrand, but do I have to consider the two cases for $x < 0$ or $x \geq 0$

One other thing, isn't the region $|x|+|y|+|z| \leq 1$ suppose to be called an octahedron.  So when i integrate over this region, should it not be two times the integral over a tetrahedron.

Thank you in advance.

Integrate the function $f(x,y,z)={x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+{z}^{2}$ over the tetrahedron

$\ E=\{(x,y,z): |x|+|y|+|z| \leq 1\} $

Integrate the function $f(x,y,z)=|z|$ over the tetrahedron

$\ E=\{(x,y,z): |x|+|y|+|z| \leq 1\} $

Integrate $f(x,y,z)=|z|$ over the surface of the sphere

$\ E=\{(x,y,z):{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+{z}^{2}=1\} $

Comment: The shape is indeed an octahedron as you said. Since the region has symmetry and the objective function is radially symmetric in x,y, and z you can just take 8 times the integral of the portion of the octant in the first (or any) quadrant. Similar statements hold for the third problem over the sphere.

Comment: @Casey, thank you for replying.  There is one other thing i want to ask.  For the second problem, because i have the $|z|$ term, don't I have to multiply the total integral by two.  Since I am integrating over an octahedron, I would have to multiply the entire integral by 16 times the integral over the first quadrant.  Thank you

Comment: What is $|z|$ is you're restricted to the first octant? Maybe try doing the problem with one fewer variable to get some intuition (i.e. $f(x,y)= |y|$ where $E = \{(x,y) :|x|+|y|\le 1\})$). The region $E$ is just a diamond to help get things started

Comment: @Casey, don't I have to consider the case when $z < 0?$

Comment: How can $z<0$ if you're integrating only over a region in the first quadrant? Again, think about the two independent variable case to convince your intuition. You're integrating over a diamond trying to find the volume under $f(x,y) = |y|$. This surface is basically a V shaped trough running up and down the x-axis. Now consider the shape of the solid only in the first quadrant.

Comment: @Casey, sorry, i should have mentioned.  So in the case of the diamond, I am accounting for both positive and negative region.  So it would be twice the area of a triangle.  So should I treat $y$ to account for both non negative and negative cases.  Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76419/discussion-between-casey-and-seth-mai).